# Special Drivers for accessing parallel port in Windows xp/7

Tags: c, windows, drivers

I just read in a few articles that we need some kind of special drivers for parallel port to access it through C as in win xp and 7 we cannot access them directly.

Can someone help me do this?

Comment: http://retired.beyondlogic.org/porttalk/porttalk.htm

Answer (score 0):

Correct. You need driver to access ports. If your purpose is to just read write data to ports for experimentation, you can use the sample(WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\general\portio) provided with WDK to experiment with ports. The sample provides driver that you can build and install
and gives a sample user mode program describing how to use the Ioctls to achieve the desired port IO.